# Exact match of column data to be retrieved

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I have scenario where i need to retrieve record only when two columns from two different tables needs to exactly match

```
Table A
--------
Column1 Column2
Item1    Code1
Item1    Code2
Item1    Code3
Item1    Code4

Table B
-------

Column1 Column2 Column3
Item2   Code1    10
Item2   Code2    10
Item2   Code3    10
Item2   Code4    10

Item3   Code1    10
Item3   Code2    10
Item3   Code3    10
```

Now I need to get Column 3 from Table B only when All the Values in Column2 in both tables matches. item 3 should be ignored since not all the values of column2 in table B matches table A column 2

End Result I am expecting is

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Item1   Code1    10
Item1   Code2    10
Item1   Code3    10
Item1   Code4    10
```

Suggestion pls for this SQL.

Comment: why do you have multiple DBs in your tags?

Comment: what if item3 did have code4? Should you see item1 8 times?

Comment: item 1 should have 20 as value for column3 for code 1

Comment: @user3723562 based on your comment "item 1 should have 20 as value for column3 for code 1" I think you really need to rethink your question... because wat

Comment: @Kritner no the op wants to show just the corresponding column3 for an item that matches the number of 'Codes' that a particular different item has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try an inner join with a subquery.. the having clause is key here to make sure that it matches all 4 conditions.

## Query

```
SELECT a.*, b.column3 
FROM tablea a
JOIN tableb b on b.column2 = a.column2
WHERE b.column1 IN
(   SELECT b.column1
    FROM tableB b
    WHERE b.column2 in(select column2 from tablea)
    GROUP BY b.column1
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
);
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cadf5f/2)

## OUTPUT

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Item1   Code1   10
Item1   Code2   10
Item1   Code3   10
Item1   Code4   10
```

## NOTE:

if you dont actually know the number of codes for a particular item you can also make it dynamic like this.

```
SELECT a.*, b.column3 
FROM tablea a
JOIN tableb b on b.column2 = a.column2
WHERE b.column1 IN
(   SELECT b.column1
    FROM tableB b
    WHERE b.column2 in(select column2 from tablea)
    GROUP BY b.column1
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT count(*) from tablea where column1 = 'Item1')
);
```

all you need to know is the product you want to match.. aka which item

Comment: inner join will result retriving item 3 for code1/code2/code3 as well right